# cv2.opencv(4.5.5) error: (-2:Unspecified error) FAILED: fs.is_open(). Can't open".caffemodel" in function 'cv::dnn::ReadProtoFromBinaryFile'

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I am triyng to run app.py file in django. This is for face_recognition for login. But at rendering time it is throwing error **cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\caffe\caffe_io.cpp:1138: error: (-2:Unspecified error) FAILED: fs.is_open(). Can't open "face_recognition_and_liveness/face_liveness_detection/face_detector\res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel" in function 'cv::dnn::ReadProtoFromBinaryFile'** even though this the path *D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\caffe\caffe_io.cpp* does not exist in my system.

I tried :

1. to take the path *D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\caffe\caffe_io.cpp* and paste in file explorer path and that is showing the path does not exit.[img that file the mentioned above file does not exit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7DXr.png)

The file res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel exits in the file path ** **
[img of file path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zybas.png)
I have installed opencv.

Comment: problem is, that `face_recognition_and_liveness/face_liveness_detection/face_detector\res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel` does not exist. and no as a python user, you do not have the cpp src code for the cv2 module

Comment: @berak face_recognition_and_liveness/face_liveness_detection/face_detector\res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel this is present. I have attached the file path.

Comment: @ISHITAKUMARI, Have you solved the problem? If so then please share its solution. because i am facing the problem as you mentioned in your question.